# How to setup static routes between multiple home networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

I have multiple networks at home and I am trying to setup static routes so computers on different networks can see each other.  I don't generally do networking, so I am probably missing something basic.

In case the diagram isn't that clear, I have a Linkskey router hooked up to the fiber modem.  I then have:

- A TP-Link ER605 Wired Router connected to the Linkskey
- A TP-Link Archer A8 WiFi Router connecter to the Linkskey
- A AP-Link AX1800 WiFi Router connected to the Linkskey

Below is my network layout.  I have tried to add static routes between the different networks but nothing is working.
For example, on "Wireless B" I added a static route to ER605 wired with these settings:

- Network Destination: 10.0.0.0
- subnet: 255.255.255.0
- gateway: 10.0.1.1
- interface: wan

I also tried different gateways (10.0.0.1, gateway of the 10.0.0.0 network, and 10.0.1.3, WAN ip address of the 10.0.0.1 LAN) but couldn't get computers on any of the different networks to "see" each other (I have tried pings and remote desktop to see if they can "see" each other).

[image: Home Network Layout]

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you really need more than one network, or can you set the 3 other routers to bridge mode so that you will have one big network? If you "generally don't do networking" then I think having multiple networks is a mistake and you're making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I need three networks.  One wireless that has limited hours, one wired for work stuff, and one wireless that is always on for cameras and my security system   they all work fine connecting to the internet, but I would like to get things setup so each computer/tv/etc can communicate with others.

Comment: Note that separate wireless networks don't have to be actually separate networks - you can have two or three wireless networks that actually connect you to the same one big network.

Comment: The wireless router I am using that allows me to shut it down for certain hours won't work that way from what I can tell.  It is consumer grade, so it has limited functionality :)

Comment: most consumer-grade routers do have bridge mode. It might also be called something else, like access point mode.